# How to retrieve document with aggregation or LINQ using $substr in mongodb C# driver

Tags: c#, linq

I'd like to retrieve data from mongodb using a c# driver and I'm having difficulty to use aggregation framework to retrieve documents async.

1. I have more than hundread thousand documents and trying to get all id's async is taking too long to get back all id's.
2. Base on all id's i am iterate foreach loop enter code here match that id and -get that documents data but while retrieve data I like to use $substr
   -on list of string see the attached raw data set.

+e.g in `db = string["one", "two", "three"]`
     in query looking while iterate list of `string["ne","wo","hr"]`

C# Model:

```
public class ThirtyTwoZero
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string SequenceNo { get; set; }
    public List<string> ThirtyTwoZeroList { get; set; }
}
```

[First DocumentSet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qk0M.png)
[Secound DocumentSet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C74zK.png)

Appreciate for any help and Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: I tried my best to improve this post, but #2 is fairly difficult to understand. Please read back your question, and rewrite it so we can better understand it.